# I want to add marker on map and zoom to that location

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I am developing app in which i can see map and place some marker on it and zoom to that location.

i successfully displayed my map view . but after adding marker and zooming code its forcefully closed... please guide me i have given my code below and also my log cat post.

```
package com.appeal.my_map;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;



public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private GoogleMap googlemap;

double latitude = 17.385044;
double longitude = 78.486671;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    marker();

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
            new LatLng(17.385044, 78.486671)).zoom(12).build();

googlemap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

}




private void marker() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps ");
    googlemap.addMarker(marker);
    googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


}
```

**My xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment 
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Log Cat**

```
7561    com.appeal.my_map   AndroidRuntime  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
7561    com.appeal.my_map   AndroidRuntime  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable     to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appeal.my_map/com.appeal.my_map.MainActivity}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
7561    com.appeal.my_map   AndroidRuntime  at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
7561    com.appeal.my_map   AndroidRuntime  at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
7561    com.appeal.my_map   AndroidRuntime  at     android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
7561    com.appeal.my_map   AndroidRuntime  at     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
7561    com.appeal.my_map   AndroidRuntime  at     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
7561    com.appeal.my_map   AndroidRuntime  at     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
7561    com.appeal.my_map   AndroidRuntime  at     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
7561    com.appeal.my_map   AndroidRuntime  at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
7561    com.appeal.my_map   AndroidRuntime  at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
7561    com.appeal.my_map   AndroidRuntime  at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
7561    com.appeal.my_map   AndroidRuntime  at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
7561    com.appeal.my_map   AndroidRuntime  at     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
7561    com.appeal.my_map   AndroidRuntime  Caused by:     java.lang.NullPointerException
7561    com.appeal.my_map   AndroidRuntime  at     com.appeal.my_map.MainActivity.marker(MainActivity.java:41)
7561    com.appeal.my_map   AndroidRuntime  at     com.appeal.my_map.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
7561    com.appeal.my_map   AndroidRuntime  at     android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
7561    com.appeal.my_map   AndroidRuntime  at     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
7561    com.appeal.my_map   AndroidRuntime  at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
7561    com.appeal.my_map   AndroidRuntime  ... 11 more
```

please correct me where am going wrong...
Thank you...!

Comment: Your log says you are getting NullPointerException at line no 41. See what is causing the error

Comment: Did you fix the problem?

Comment: yes, please read answer given below by  Raghunandan for solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not initialized `googlemap`. You need to initialize the same

```
 SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
 googlemap = fm.getMap();
```

Comment: but if i removed code of adding marker and for zooming its working i can see map on my device.

Comment: so what you are using the google map object without initializing. SO you will get NPE. check the end of this page https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: @YograjShinde check the third step in the link posted it says build and run the application you should see the map they have not initialized GoogleMap object. But in your code you have not initialized but you are trying to use the same and so you run into NPE

Comment: @YograjShinde you can also upvote the answer if it helps now that you have enough reputations

Answer (score 0):

GoogleMap is empty? Try to initialize GoogleMap  first and then add markers. Otherwise you will get a NullPointer exception.

```
googleMap = (GoogleMap)...findViewById(R.id.....);
```